# Python - doesn't write to file?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write to a file like this:

```
debugfile = open("file.txt", "w")
debugfile.write("%i" % (feature['properties']['cellId']))
debugfile.close()
```

Here `feature['properties']['cellId']` is an integer. The file is created, but stays empty. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I tried writing to the console.

```
debugfile = open("file.txt", "w")
print(feature['properties']['cellId'])
debugfile.write("%i" % (feature['properties']['cellId']))
debugfile.close()
```

This shows the console:
[image]
The file is still empty.

Comment: I don't know what `feature` is so can't test, but `debugfile.write("%i" % 42)` works fine. So something else is wrong. Are any errors raised? Can you update your example to something that fails for you but that we can run? Maybe add `print(`feature['properties']['cellId'])` then post that?

Comment: LOL - you did! that as fast.

Comment: Try to print with the string formatting

Comment: Okay, so this is part of a larger loop? You keep opening in "w" mode, which overwrites the content, so you have at most 1 item. If your loop has a conditional (an `if`) after the open which skips the write, then you'll have an empty file. Open in `"a"` mode instead.

Comment: you have this file open in some editor while you write on it with this code? if so, close it, use this code and open it again

Comment: Can you show your dict?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value by printing `feature['properties']['cellId']`.

If I initialize `feature`,

```
feature = {'properties':{'cellId':1}}
```

the code works. So there's nothing wrong with the code.

```
debugfile = open("file.txt", "w")
debugfile.write("%i" % (feature['properties']['cellId']))
debugfile.close()
```

Comment: Updated the question. Appears on the console, not in the file.

Comment: It looks like you are writing this in a loop & the values are getting overwritten as suggested by @tdelaney. You might get a better answer if you share the code with more context i.e. with the loop.

Answer (score -2):

Aren't you trying to write a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)?

---

Never mind, this works either way:

```
#!python
#coding=utf-8

import sys
print(sys.version)

debugfile = open("file1.txt", "w")
debugfile.write("%i" % (123))
debugfile.close()

debugfile = open("file2.txt", "w")
debugfile.write("%i" % 123)
debugfile.close()
```

Comment: That's normal for old-style formatting. If the format string has only ` 1 substitution, you can pass in an object or a 1 element tuple. If there are more substitutions, you pass in a tuple for each.

Comment: Right: [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), second paragraph.